# Lighttpd fastcgi urls not rewritten

Tags: lighttpd, web.py, fastcgi

I have a lighttpd server with fastcgi and web.py with the following fcgi configuration:

```
fastcgi.server = ( "/code.py" => 
(( "socket" => "/tmp/fastcgi.socket",
   "bin-path" => "/etc/lighttpd/code/code.py",
   "check-local" => "disable",
   "max-procs" => 1
```

))
)

and main config:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
  "^(.*)/favicon.ico$"  => "/static/favicon.ico",
  "^/static/(.*)$"      => "/static/$1",
  "^/code.py(.*)$"      => "/code.py/404",
  "^/forum(.*)$"        => "/code.py/forum/$1"
)
```

If I go to www.mysite.com/forum everything works as it's supposed to, but if I go to www.mysite.com/code.py/forum I am not redirected to a 404 as I'm supposed to, but actually get the first link.
I basically want to hide my internals from the outside world.

I looked in the error log and it seems that the server is indeed rewriting the url, and yet it doesn't make a difference.

```
(response.c.300) -- splitting Request-URI 
(response.c.301) Request-URI  :  /code.py/forum 
(response.c.302) URI-scheme   :  https 
(response.c.303) URI-authority:  www.mysite.com 
(response.c.304) URI-path     :  /code.py/forum 
(response.c.305) URI-query    :   
(response.c.300) -- splitting Request-URI 
(response.c.301) Request-URI  :  /code.py/404 
(response.c.302) URI-scheme   :  https 
(response.c.303) URI-authority:  www.mysite.com 
(response.c.304) URI-path     :  /code.py/404 
(response.c.305) URI-query    :   
(response.c.349) -- sanatising URI 
(response.c.350) URI-path     :  /code.py/404 
(mod_access.c.135) -- mod_access_uri_handler called 
(mod_fastcgi.c.3609) handling it in mod_fastcgi 
(response.c.470) -- before doc_root 
(response.c.471) Doc-Root     : /var/www/html 
(response.c.472) Rel-Path     : /code.py 
(response.c.473) Path         :  
(response.c.521) -- after doc_root 
(response.c.522) Doc-Root     : /var/www/html 
(response.c.523) Rel-Path     : /code.py 
(response.c.524) Path         : /var/www/html/code.py 
(response.c.541) -- logical -> physical 
(response.c.542) Doc-Root     : /var/www/html 
(response.c.543) Rel-Path     : /code.py 
(response.c.544) Path         : /var/www/html/code.py 
(mod_fastcgi.c.3035) got proc: pid: 30262 socket: unix:/tmp/fastcgi.socket-0 load: 1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
  "^/favicon\.ico$" => "/static/favicon.ico",
  "^/forum(.*)$" => "/forum/code.py$1"
)

$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/forum(.*)$" { 
  ( "/code.py" => 
    (( "socket" => "/tmp/fastcgi.socket",
       "bin-path" => "/etc/lighttpd/code/code.py",
       "check-local" => "disable",
       "max-procs" => 1,
       "bin-environment" => ("REAL_SCRIPT_NAME" => "")
    ))
  )
}
```

Comment: I am aware of it, and it doesn't help. I want to have my website to simply go to index.html, and anything going towards mysite.com/forum to be handled by the fastcgi process.

The problem is that I don't want to allow urls of the type "mysite.com/code.py/forum" to be legal (see the config I have in my main question, I try redirecting to 404 and it doesn't work).

Comment: Have you tried setting `"bin-environment" => ("REAL_SCRIPT_NAME" => "")` ?

Comment: I think you should enable fastcgi only for `/forum` subpath. `$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/forum(.*)$" { fastcgi.server = ( "/code.py" => ` check http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModFastCGI

Comment: It seems `"bin-environment" => ("REAL_SCRIPT_NAME" => "")` did the trick. I'm not yet sure what it does, I'll figure it out while I test it doesn't have any unwanted side effects. And I'll enable fastcgi only for the subpath. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry for the confusion, I used to run lighttpd environment long time ago, now my preferred ways of deploying web.py apps are either nginx+uwsgi or apache2+mod_wsgi.